# How to walk through Rust enum fields in GDB or LLDB?

Tags: gdb, rust, lldb

I have this code:

```
struct Foo {
    id: i32,
}
enum Bar {
    Variant(Foo),
}

fn main() {
    let x = Bar::Variant(Foo { id: 100 });
    println!("set breakpoint here");
}
```

How can I print the memory address of the `Foo` instance?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `PascalCase` for structs / enums / enum variants. Since the casing of your types isn't important to the question, I've changed them, which also improves the code highlighting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a recent GDB that has built-in Rust debugging support, you can use Rust-ish syntax:

```
(gdb) p &x.0.id
$3 = (i32 *) 0x7fffffffe0f0
```

GDB knows which variant of an enum is in use, so `x.0` names the `Foo` in `x` (because `Variant` is a tuple).  The `.id` names the `i32`, and `&` takes the address.

Comment: I am use GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12.1: '(gdb) p &x.0.id' prints 
'Rust debug format has changed'

Comment: What version of rust are you using?  It's probably a gdb bug but it's hard to know for sure.  I can try to reproduce it though.

Comment: rustc 1.18.0-nightly (452bf0852 2017-04-19)

Comment: You need a newer gdb.  I'm not sure exactly when this was fixed, maybe back in October.  Anyway, gdb 7.12 has the bug, but my gdb build from git does not.